# Derivative of $\sin(-x) = -\cos(x)$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Doesn't derivative of $\sin(-x)$ equal:

$f'(x) = \cos(-x)(-1)$
$f'(x)= -\cos(-x)$

how do you get $-\cos x$?

Comment: cos(-x)=cosx as cos is an even function, similarly sin is an odd function so sin(x)=-sin(-x), odd and even functions have certain characteristics you should get to know graphically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\cos(x)$ is an even function which means $\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$. Using this we have $-\cos(-x)=-\cos(x)$

Comment: thank you! but what does being even have to do with it?

Comment: Because being even essentially means you can remove a minus sign from inside the argument. That's why your answer and $-\cos(x)$ are the samething.

Comment: @Jessica A function $f$ is called even if $f(x) = f(-x)$. This evenness has nothing to do with the evenness of numbers. It is a different concept.

Comment: @mtiano but what properties enable you to just simply remove the minus sign from inside the brackets?

Comment: @mtiano like is there a proof? or you just know?

Comment: @mtiano oh nevermind since f(-x) = f(x) so -cos(-x) just becomes cos(-x), i seeee

Comment: @LordSoth  It actually _does_ have to do with the "even-ness" of numbers, but in a hidden way: the Maclaurin series of an "even" function only contains terms with even integer powers of $ \ x \ $ , an "odd" function, only odd integer powers.  (The terminology itself comes from $ \ y = x^n \ $ being an even [odd] function when $ \ n \ $ is an even [odd] integer.)